# How to use the common javascript files for both desktop and mobile web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, web

I have written some web pages with both desktop and mobile versions. However, the js files are almost the same. So I start to wonder that if
I can reduce the code size by accessing the same js files in both desktop and mobile web.

This is my webpage directory:

DekstopDir/

- *.html (All html files in desktop)
- css/
- javascript/
- m/ (which provides all the mobile pages)

  - *.html (All html files in mobile)
  - css/
  - javascript/

I found that too much js files are duplicated. Is any way to reduce the code size?

Update:
Here is a stupid solution I think it probably can work; nevertheless, I haven't saw anyone do this:

Certain html file in the mobile directory:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/TheSameJs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use functions. Share them.

Comment: @Quentin I'm sorry that I didn't get it... 
In one html file, I can only type `<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx.js"></script>` Should I write `<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/xxx.js"></script>` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, there's one thing that you could try. What you can do is if there are similar codes that you are using with **Js** or **Css** then you wouldn't have to duplicate them into 2 platforms (Mobile, Desktop).

So you could make **another file** that has similar codes for both the mobile and desktop html files and at the same time delete those codes from the 2 dups to make space and reduce the size.

Hope this helps.